# How to select file and upload file using Angular 6 in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular6-json-schema-form

Here we need to Add Test case, For that we need to upload a file using input type file using angular 6 in reactive Forms.
while Uploading a file and sending as response to API,we are getting Response in the headers as

```
test_template: "C:\fakepath\Copy of Task_angular_issue and change_logs.xlsx"
```

But in the response we are getting as

```js
{
  "Status": "Error",
  "Message": "Following parameter(s) are missing: test_script,test_template",
  "Result": []
}
```

Can, I know how to upload a file

html file

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <form class="example-form" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="addAutomationCase(this.login_type)">
    <div class="example-full-width" style="display: inline-block">
      <label>Template Upload</label>
      <input type="file" formControlName="test_template" accept=".xlsx,.xls" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" #fileInput>
    </div>

    <div class="dashboardFooter">
      <button type="submit" class="button btn-primary" mat-raised-button mat-button color="primary"> Save </button>
      <button type="reset" class="button btn-default" mat-raised-button mat-button color="default" [routerLink]="['/auth/admin/Manage_Automation']"> Cancel </button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

ts file

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective,FormGroup, NgForm, Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

import { AutomationCaseServiceProvider } from "../../../services/automationCase-service";
import { AuthServiceProvider } from "../../../services/auth-service";
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';
import { FilterTableComponent } from '../../../tables/filter-table/filter-table.component';

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-automation',
  templateUrl: './add-automation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-automation.component.scss'],
  providers: [ AutomationCaseServiceProvider, AuthServiceProvider]
})
export class AddAutomationComponent implements OnInit {


  account: { test_template: string } = {
    test_template: ''
  };

  userForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    public authService: AuthServiceProvider,
    public automationCaseService: AutomationCaseServiceProvider,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

   **Initialize the Form Here**

    this.buildForm();

  }


  buildForm(): void {



    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'test_template': ['', Validators.required]
      })
      console.log(this.userForm);
  };

  addAutomationCase() {
        if (!this.userForm.valid) {
          return;
        }
        else {
            this.automationCaseService.addautomationCase(this.userForm.value).subscribe(
              (resp) => {
                let UserData = JSON.stringify(resp);
                let data = JSON.parse(UserData);

                console.log(data.Message);
                if(data.Status == "Error"){
                  this.snackBar.open(data.Message,'Close', {
                    duration: 2000
                  });
                }

                else if(data.Status == "Success"){
                  this.snackBar.open(data.Message,'Close', {
                    duration: 2000
                  });
                this.router.navigate(['/auth/admin/Manage_Automation']);
                }
          });
      }
  }

  onSelectFile(event) {
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(event.target));
    // if (event.target && event.target[0]) {
    //   var reader = new FileReader();
    //   reader.readAsDataURL(event.target[0]); 
    //   // read file as data url
    //   alert(event.target.files[0]);
    // }
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
    }
    this.test_template = event.target.files[0].name;



          // need to run CD since file load runs outside of zone
          //this.cd.markForCheck()
  }

  onSelectscript(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
    }
  }

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

}
```

Comment: Your APi tells you `Following parameter(s) are missing: test_script,test_template`, so maybe add them  ?

Comment: I am Already Sending in the response to the headers{"test_template":"C:\\fakepath\\Copy of Task_angular_issue and change_logs.xlsx"}

Comment: Well apparently not ! First of all in your code it is missing `test_script`. Second, you have a `test_template` value in your form, but you edit your component object, then you send your form value through your service. Your code is full of inconsistency, and without a [mcve] no-one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a file in angular reactive form by importing RxFormBuilder from  @rxweb/reactive-form-validators, Create its object and use toFormData() method that will convert the json data to formData, Here i have passed a link of api on the server side for your reference, it will pass the fileObject to the server. When you add [writeFile]="true" in the html, you dont need to call onSelectFile($event)

Component.ts:

```
export class AddAutomationComponent implements OnInit {
   api:string = 'api/User'

  account: { test_template: string } = {
    test_template: ''
  };

  userForm: RxFormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder,private http: HttpClient ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
  }


  buildForm(): void {
    this.userForm = <RxFormGroup>this.formBuilder.group({
        'test_template': ['', Validators.required]
      })
     let formdata = this.userForm.toFormData()
       this.http.post(this.api, formdata); // This is fake uri, This is just for your reference.
  };
}
```

and in the component.html:

```
<div class="dashboard">
  <form class="example-form" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="addAutomationCase(this.login_type)">
    <div class="example-full-width" style="display: inline-block">
      <label>Template Upload</label>
      <input type="file" formControlName="test_template" accept=".xlsx,.xls" [writeFile]="true">
    </div>

    <div class="dashboardFooter">
      <button type="submit" class="button btn-primary" color="primary"> Save </button>
      <button type="reset" class="button btn-default" color="default"> Cancel </button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k66nmn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fformadata-complete.component.html)